# Can I reuse a selector in multiple areas of state?

Tags: react-redux

Say I have an area of state that holds info about a person.  Addresses, phone numbers etc.  I create selectors for that data structure.  Now say I have multiple areas of state that need to hold that data structure.  Can I reuse the selectors?  Currently I have a heirachy of selectors but at the top, they select from a single part of the store.  ie can a selector be defined in a common area and be used in different areas of the store?

Thanks
Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then sure you can. For example, define a 'base' selector like this:

```
const reusableSelector = (query, storePart) => {
  return store => query(store[storePart]);
};
```

As I imagine your state likely have a structure like this:

```
state
- workers
- managers
- etc.
```

And these collections stores person items.

`query` is the reusable function what you want to use in multiple places, like the phone numbers of a group of people:

```
const getPhoneNumbers = persons => persons.map(person => person.phoneNumber);
```

So, you can create multiple selectors from this one:

```
const workerPhoneNumbers = useSelector(getPhoneNumbers, 'workers');

const managerPhoneNumbers = useSelector(getPhoneNumbers, 'managers');
```

You can also combine multiple selectors with libraries like `[reselect][1]`.